# Mostrar elementos al presionar un radio boton

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un fomulario donde al precionar una opcion de el conjunto de radio botones e activa o no alguna parte del formulario

el codigo es el siguiente

```
<form>

<section class="dataSoli">
  <label for="">Lugar y fecha de la solicitud</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Lugar" name="lugar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" name="fecha">
</section>

<section class="genData">

  <div class="titulo">
    <h2>I. DATOS DE/LA SOLICITANTE</h2>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="soliBy" id="victimaA" value="a" onclick="activate()">
    <label for="victima">Victima</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="soliBy" id="victimaB" value="b" onclick="activate()">
    <label for="victima">Victima B</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="soliBy" id="victimaC" value="c" onclick="activate()">
    <label for="victima">Servidor publico</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="soliBy" id="victimaD" value="d" onclick="activate()">
    <label for="victima">Representante legal</label>
  </div>

  <section id="parteUno" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Contesta B y C</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="parteDos" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Contesta A , B, C</h1>
  </section>



</section>

</form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

function activate(elemento) {
  if (elemento.value == 'a') {
    document.getElementById('parteDos').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('parteOne').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    if (elemento.value == 'b' || elemento.value == 'c') {
      document.getElementById('parteDos').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('parteOne').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('parteDos').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('parteOne').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Se supone que debo ir activando partes del formulario pero no funciona, en este caso sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si dependa tambien de que tengo las CDN de bootstrap, pero no creo que sea el caso, solo dice que no procesa 'value'. O si hay otra forma mas sencilla me gustaria escucharla, apenas estoy empezando a ver como funciona js y quiero aprender lo mas que se pueda de estos errores, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes al tratar de acceder al valor de los botones de radio.

onclick() no le pasa ese parámetro "elemento" que le has dado a tu función "activate".

En su lugar tienes que acceder al valor de los botones de radio con:

document.getElementsByName('soliBy')

Que te devuelve un array donde document.getElementsByName('soliBy')[0] es el primer elemento y de ahí puedes coger el value, comprobar si esta checked, etc...

Ojo también que tienes un pequeño gazapo, hay un div que a veces le llamas parteUno y otras parteOne... ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function activate() {
    if (document.getElementsByName('soliBy')[0].checked) {
        document.getElementById('parteDos').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('parteUno').style.display = "none";
    } else if (document.getElementsByName('soliBy')[1].checked || document.getElementsByName('soliBy')[2].checked) {
        document.getElementById('parteDos').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('parteUno').style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('parteDos').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('parteUno').style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>


<form>

<section class="dataSoli">
    <label for="">Lugar y fecha de la solicitud</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Lugar" name="lugar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" name="fecha">
</section>

<section class="genData">

    <div class="titulo">
    <h2>I. DATOS DE/LA SOLICITANTE</h2>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="soliBy" id="victimaA" value="a" onclick="activate()">
    <label for="victima">Victima</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="soliBy" id="victimaB" value="b" onclick="activate()">
    <label for="victima">Victima B</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="soliBy" id="victimaC" value="c" onclick="activate()">
    <label for="victima">Servidor publico</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="soliBy" id="victimaD" value="d" onclick="activate()">
    <label for="victima">Representante legal</label>
    </div>

    <section id="parteUno" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Contesta B y C</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="parteDos" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Contesta A , B, C</h1>
    </section>



</section>

</form>
```